# Simple onclick in a row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just cant figure out what i am doing wrong in the code below:

```
<table width='100%'>

<script>$("#101m").on("click", function() {alert($( this ).text());});</script>
<tr id='101m'><td  class='dayavailible'>A</td></tr>

<script>$("#101a").on("click", function() {alert($( this ).text());});</script>
<tr id='101a'><td  class='dayavailible'>A</td></tr>

<script>$("#101e").on("click", function() {alert($( this ).text());});</script>
<tr id='101e'><td  class='dayavailible'>A</td></tr>
</table>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're attaching the event handlers before the elements exist. Place all your scripts either at the end of the page, before `</body>` or in a single script within a document.ready handler in the `<head>`

Comment: It is like waiting for a pizza before ordering it...  As a sdie not, your HTML markup is invalid, getting a script tag as child of a table

Answer (score 2):

Your onclick event couldn't bind to all the rows as at the time when script occurs there is no element present in HTML, so either move your JavaScript code after html or use `$(function(){ ... });` DOM Ready.

Though what I would suggest you is to use  modular code so that you don't have to write the same code again and again.

```
<script>
// DOM Ready
$(function(){
  $("[id*='101']").on("click", function() {
     alert($( this ).text());
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is executed before the DOM is loaded so the element doesn't exist yet, and the jQuery selector doesn't match anything, so no elements get a click handler bound to them. You need to call the `init()` method with in [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#101a").on("click", function() {
      alert($( this ).text());
   });
});
```

OR, move your script to the end of page before `</body>` tag.